# function for creating general variables

Tags: r

i want to create a function where i can create a general variables like data from below table for example if i give grace_type = National then it will create general variables Grace 1, grace 2 m grce 3, grace 4 as (2,2,6,9)

the same way i want to give for continental , national, Rural.....

```
for example if i give global option as grace_type = National then
Grace 1 should automatically to 2
Grace 2 should automatically to 2
Grace 3 should automatically to 6
Grace 4 should automatically to 9
```

Comment: if you have no knowledge of R then do a basic R tutorial- e.g. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-r

Comment: Welcome to SO. Some pointers to get a positive response to a question:  please don’t use images [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Questions should be reproducible. This makes it easy for other who may want to help, copy data easily. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`. [Good overview on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try this gentle introduction to R at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/r/r_data_frames.asp) You will find that this kind of operations are a infinitely  easier to perform in R than in more 'traditional' language like C or Java

Comment: @Mark i have tried ifelse but it will be very long

Comment: It's hard to give an answer for your context without more information. It sounds like you just want to get the information from the National column, which you would get with df$National, assuming the table is named df

Comment: @Mark i just realised the problem so i have updated the question

Comment: generally speaking, in R it's not a good idea to make many variables which are all the same data- it's better to keep things in a list or a vector. E.g. if I'm storing temperature data, I wouldn't make a variable `temperature_25-11-2023`, another  `temperature_24-11-2023`, and so on, I'd make a dataframe with a date column and a temperature column, or something similar

Comment: if you're just wanting to create a function which returns the values in the column you give (e.g. National), then that is straightforward

Comment: you can use global option